# How to calculate that how many times tick event occur?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What I really want to do, I want to calculate that how many times tick event occur. Actually I want to make check on it that if this event occurs 5 time. 
Then messagebox should displayed.
Here is my code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int i = 0;
    int points = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {            
      System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
      dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(this.playMyAudioFile);

      TimeSpan ts = dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);

      dispatcherTimer.Start();
      if (counter == 5)
      {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();            
      }

      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // some code    
        label1.Content = points;
        }
    }

    private void playMyAudioFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rd = new Random();            
        i = rd.Next(1, 26);            
        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(@"D:\Project C#\A-Z\" + i + ".mp3");
        mediaElement1.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` in your textBox1_TextChanged event handler.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you're not using `Random()` correctly. You are initializing the pseudo random generator each time, before you call `Next` on it which will cause the sequence of random numbers generated to not be very random.

Answer (score 1):

Using `await`, instead of a timer, makes this particular task much easier:

```
public static async Task makeMusic(TimeSpan timespan)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //this assumes you can remove the parameters from this method
        playMyAudioFile(); 
        await Task.Delay(timespan);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("All done!");
}
```

You can make the count a parameter, if it needs to be configurable, or remove the `timespan` as a parameter if it need never change.

Answer (score 0):

Servy's solution is a lot cleaner than using a timer. But if you insist on using a timer, I would suggest this:

```
private int counter = 0;
private Random rd = new Random();
private void playMyAudioFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i = rd.Next(1, 26);            
    mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(@"D:\Project C#\A-Z\" + i + ".mp3");
    mediaElement1.Play();
    ++counter;
    if (counter == 5)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

I *think* that the `sender` is the dispatcher timer, so you can probably write:

```
var timer = (DispatcherTimer)sender;
timer.Stop();
```

And, please, replace this:

```
TimeSpan ts = dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
```

With:

```
TimeSpan ts = dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
```

When I see `new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)`, I have to think about what that signifies. Is it minutes, seconds, and milliseconds? Days, hours, and minutes? Hours, minutes, and seconds?

`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)`, though, is explicit. There is absolutely no ambiguity.